# Format NTFS external drive to OSX

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive

Is there anyway of converting an external drive which is NTFS to OSX...I don't want to be able to write to NTFS from my Mac, I want to format the drive and use it as if its made for OSX in OSX format.

Comment: … keeping its contents intact, that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After backing up the contents of the drive (formatting it to HFS+ (OS X native) will erase all the data on it).

You can use `disk utility` to format the drive (found under Applications/Utilities).

You'll see your drive listed on the left hand side.  Select it and then choose to Partition it into one partition and select the format "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" then apply.

After that you should have a MAC formatted drive (not usable with Windows PCs).  Depending on the size of the drive you could also opt for MS-DOS (fat), this will allow you to use the drive with both Macs and PCs interchangeably.  NTFS is not Mac friendly (though it can be worked around, there are several commercial and open source projects to read+write NTFS on a Mac) and HFS+ is not Windows friendly.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GParted if data can be earsed.

Burn it into a CD.

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

support HFS+/UFS